# Save custom array of objects to file and read again in java?

Tags: java, arrays, file, object, save

I would like to save an array of objects that is custom as a file and re-read it back as an array of objects on program start in java. If I could also save it as JSON, it would be nice. I have tried some common methods but I get a error saying that my array is not serialiazable.

```
class ArrayOfObjects {

  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

    Students[] studentArray = new Students[3];
    studentArray[0] = new Students();
    studentArray[0].age = 18;
    studentArray[0].name = "Jones";
    studentArray[1] = new Students();
    studentArray[1].age = 21;
    studentArray[1].name = "David";
    studentArray[2] = new Students();
    studentArray[2].age = 15;
    studentArray[2].name = "Jeremy";
  }  

}

class Students {

  int age;
  String name;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

your class Students should implement Serialiazble

Comment: That sort of worked. I got this now. http://pastebin.com/6fwMEptN
Also, how do I re-read it into the same array?

Comment: you use ObjectInputStream

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to save it in standard output, Students must implement Serializable.
2. If you wan to save it as JSON, use Jackson (http://fasterxml.com/) and normalise it Java bean declaration to the class.

   ```
   class Students implemenst Serializable {

     private int age;
     private String name;

     public int getAge() {
         return age;
     }

     public void setAge(int age) {
         this.age = age;
     }

     public String getName() {
         return name;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
     }

   }
   ```